# ERROR TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function

Tags: angular

I'm getting error, ERROR TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function
Whats wrong with it ?

> ```
> import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
> import { AngularFireDatabase } from 'angularfire2/database';
> import { AngularFireAuth} from 'angularfire2/auth';
> import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';
>
> import 'rxjs/add/operator/take';
> import { BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
>
> @Injectable()
> export class MessagingService {
>
> messaging = firebase.messaging();
> currentMessage = new BehaviorSubject(null);
>
> constructor(private db: AngularFireDatabase, private afAuth: 
> AngularFireAuth) {
> }
>
> private updateToken(token) {
>   this.afAuth.authState.take(1).subscribe(user => {
>     if (!user) { return; }
>
>     const data = { [user.uid]: token };
>     this.db.object('fcmTokens/').update(data);
>   });
> }
>
> getPermission() {
>     this.messaging.requestPermission()
>         .then(() => {
>             console.log('Notification permission granted.');
>             return this.messaging.getToken();
>         })
>         .then(token => {
>             console.log(token);
>             this.updateToken(token);
>         })
>         .catch((err) => {
>             console.log('Unable to get permission to notify.', err);
>         });
> } 
>
> receiveMessage() {
>     this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
>         console.log('Message received. ', payload);
>         this.currentMessage.next(payload);
>     });
>   }
> }
> ```

`ERROR TypeError: firebase.messaging is not a function`

I'm having big probleems with that error, I don't have any idea how to fix that, please help me repair that code. I've done everything like an example, but it doesn't work. thank you so much for your answers.

Comment: Any solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

Try changing

`import * as firebase from 'firebase/app';`

to

`import * as firebase from 'firebase';`